# Add not null DateTime column to SQLite without default value?

Tags: sqlite

I can't add a not null constraint or remove a default constraint. I would like to add a datetime column to a table and have all the values set to anything (perhaps 1970 or year 2000) but it seems like i cant use not null without a default and I cant remove a default once added in. So how can i add this column? (once again just a plain datetime not null)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of using `ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN`, create a new table that has the extra column, and copy your old data.  This will free you from the restrictions of `ALTER TABLE` and let you have a `NOT NULL` constraint without a default value.

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable RENAME TO OldTable;
CREATE TABLE YourTable (/* old cols */, NewColumn DATETIME NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO YourTable SELECT *, '2000-01-01 00:00:00' FROM OldTable;
DROP TABLE OldTable;
```

**Edit:** The official SQLite documentation for [ALTER TABLE](https://sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) now warns against the above procedure because it “might corrupt references to that table in triggers, views, and foreign key constraints.”  The safe alternative is to use a temporary name for the *new* table, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE NewTable (/* old cols */, NewColumn DATETIME NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO NewTable SELECT *, '2000-01-01 00:00:00' FROM YourTable;
DROP TABLE YourTable;
ALTER TABLE NewTable RENAME TO YourTable;
```