# Altering and adding column to the table in sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

If I alter the table and add a new column will add the data be wiped off from that table.

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN noOfDays integer default 0 NOT NULL
```

Will the above SQL command drop MyTable and then ALTER it with the noOfDays column or will it simply add the noOfDays column without dropping it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `add` just adds the column. Neither its data will be deleted nor the table be dropped.

p.s. from the documentation 
"Note: also that when adding a CHECK constraint, the CHECK constraint is not tested against preexisting rows of the table." (check [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) manual for more)

Comment: As far as I remember you have to update the default value to existing rows (couldn't find it in the documentation right now); check for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492947/insert-a-not-null-column-to-an-existing-table

Comment: I believe my SQL above will create a noOfDays column and insert 0 as the default value.

Comment: Why did you do this UPDATE MyTable SET noOfDays = 0; should it not default to 0 once the column is created!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; your `ALTER` command works well; however, there is a restriction on check constraints - will add this as a note above